# Getting PHP to query MySQL for a COUNT() without GROUPING

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get a PHP-script to show all duplicate values in a MySQL-table. Using the following code I get the wanted results in the phpMyAdmin SQL-query window but it won't work as a PHP mysql_query().

```
SELECT nordby_log.artikel, a.the_count
FROM
  nordby_log, 
  (SELECT artikel, COUNT(*) AS the_count
  FROM nordby_log
  GROUP BY artikel) AS a
WHERE nordby_log.artikel = a.artikel
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you mean the phpmyadmin result for this query is diffrent of php mysql_query result?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `HAVING`, which is evaluated *after* results have been grouped:

```sql
SELECT   artikel
FROM     nordby_log
GROUP BY artikel
HAVING   COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: +1 was my fallback when you pointed out my error. Deleting my answer.